# auto-migrate as3 to as2 (yeah, backwards)

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have some as3 code under development that I'd like to migrate to as2 periodically.  Does anyone have a script for that?  Or do I have to scrap it, start developing in as2 instead, and grab an as2->as3 migration tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to start developing in AS2 and use a migration tool if need be.

This sounds like it will bring up problems in the future when the project gets larger. There are also new features in AS3 that will not be available in AS2.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have way more luck and about 3432x less frustration if you go from AS2 -> AS3. Converting OOP into all timeline code will be a **nightmare**, but converting AS2 syntax in the timeline to AS3 syntax will be a little easier.